# i need to create unique id in node.js without register

Tags: javascript, node.js, unique-id

I need to receive unique id in node.js when user not login or register.
I used the `request-ip` package also used `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` and  `req.connection.remoteAddress`
but The IP in these commands varies according to the Internet and is not unique to each browser

Comment: An IP address is not unique for browser. It's not even unique for a computer. 10 people can sit in a cafe with their laptops and share the same public IP address. On the other site an IP address can change in a session. My internet service provider changes my IP address regularly. Sometime I use a VPN bound to one device. One request can be send through the VPN and the very next request can be send through my own network.

Comment: Create a unique ID in the backend and store it in a cookie, local storage or session storage.

Comment: Just [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) npm module. And all you need to do is `uuidv4()` to generate unique IDs. Check it's docs. Then send that uuid to browser and store in `localStorage` and backend DB to auth the user. as @jabaa said.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware for your application. In this middleware check if the user is not log in and the request does not contain some special header (for example `["first-token"]`) then create a big random string:

```js
const token = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
```

and send it to your client. for example:

```js
res.json({firstToken: token, /*Other fields you may need to send*/});
```

Then in your client side store it in cookie or local storage.
Cookie:

```
document.cookie = document.cookie + "; firstToken=" + firstToken
```

LocalStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("firstToken", firstToken);
```

And after that you should send this cookie in every request you send to the server. In this example in `["first-token"]` header.

This way you assign a unique random string to user and you do not change it until they clear their browser data.